# GetNamedSecurityInfo returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED(5) when writting owner of a remote Windows shared folder

Tags: c++, winapi, active-directory, access-denied

I'm a Domain Admin and I want to take ownership of some shared folders on some server of my domain programmatically in API(for example C++). I did some reading work and found that a Domain Admin is in the member machine's Local Admins group by default, and the Local Admins users can take ownership anyway. I just wrtie some code in this way but still encountered ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED when getting the owner sid using GetNamedSecurityInfo? Where's the problem?

Something interesting is: When I changed the GetNamedSecurityInfo's secound argument from SE_FILE_OBJECT to SE_LMSHARE, it would succeed(also set one). But I didn't see the owner changed in the "Security" tab of folder's properties. I know a "share" permission is different with "security" one. a "share" permission even don't have a owner. So what owner did I get when calling GetNamedSecurityInfo by the SE_LMSHARE argument?

Here's the function i use for Taking ownership for the folder "strFileName", on server "strServerName", the owner changed to is just the Domain Admin account known as "strDomainName" "strUserName" "strPassword", orginal owner is reserved in "pOriginSID".
I got error code 5 in the GetNamedSecurityInfo call (also the Set one). I also write a impersonation method "logOnByUserPassword" which seems not to work, i paste it below.

HANDLE ADPermissionSearch::getAccessTokenByCredential(CString strDomainName, CString strUserName, CString strPassword)
{

```
CString strUPNUserName = strUserName + _T("@") + strDomainName;

HANDLE hToken;
BOOL bResult;
//bResult = LogonUser(strUserName, strDomainName, strPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
//  &hToken);
if (strDomainName != _T(""))
{
    bResult = LogonUser(strUPNUserName, _T(""), strPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, 
        &hToken);
}
else
{
    bResult = LogonUser(strUserName, _T("."), strPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, 
        &hToken);
}
if (bResult == FALSE)
{
    MyMessageBox_Error(_T("getAccessTokenByCredential Error."), _T("Error"));
    return FALSE;
}
else
{
    return hToken;
}
```

}

int ADPermissionSearch::takeOwnership(CString strServerName, CString strFileName, CString strDomainName, CString strUserName, CString strPassword, __out PSID &pOriginSID)
{

```
CString strUNCFileName = _T("\\\\") + strServerName + _T("\\") + strFileName;
_bstr_t bstrUNCFileName = _bstr_t(strUNCFileName);
PSID pSIDAdmin = NULL;
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthNT = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
HANDLE hToken = NULL;
DWORD dwRes;

// Create a SID for the BUILTIN\Administrators group.
if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthNT, 2,
    SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
    DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    &pSIDAdmin))
{
    if (pSIDAdmin)
        FreeSid(pSIDAdmin);
    if (hToken)
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    MyMessageBox_Error(_T("takeOwnership"));
    return 0;
}

// If the preceding call failed because access was denied,
// enable the SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME privilege, create a SID for
// the Administrators group, take ownership of the object, and
// disable the privilege. Then try again to set the object's DACL.

// Open a handle to the access token for the calling process.
/*
if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
                      TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,
                      &hToken))
{
    if (pSIDAdmin)
        FreeSid(pSIDAdmin);
    if (hToken)
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    MyMessageBox_Error(_T("takeOwnership"));
    return 0;
}
*/
if ((hToken = getAccessTokenByCredential(strDomainName, strUserName, strPassword)) == NULL)
{
    if (pSIDAdmin)
        FreeSid(pSIDAdmin);
    if (hToken)
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    MyMessageBox_Error(_T("takeOwnership"));
    return 0;
}

// Enable the SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME privilege.
if (!setPrivilege(hToken, SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME, TRUE))
{
    if (pSIDAdmin)
        FreeSid(pSIDAdmin);
    if (hToken)
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    MyMessageBox_Error(_T("takeOwnership"));
    return 0;
}

// Get the original owner in the object's security descriptor.
dwRes = GetNamedSecurityInfo(
    bstrUNCFileName,             // name of the object
    SE_FILE_OBJECT,                  // type of object
    OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION,  // change only the object's owner
    &pOriginSID,                 // SID of Administrator group
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL);
if (dwRes != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    if (pSIDAdmin)
        FreeSid(pSIDAdmin);
    if (hToken)
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    MyMessageBox_Error(_T("takeOwnership"));
    return 0;
}

// Set the owner in the object's security descriptor.
dwRes = SetNamedSecurityInfo(
            bstrUNCFileName,             // name of the object
            SE_FILE_OBJECT,                  // type of object
            OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION,  // change only the object's owner
            pSIDAdmin,                   // SID of Administrator group
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL);
if (dwRes != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    if (pSIDAdmin)
        FreeSid(pSIDAdmin);
    if (hToken)
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    MyMessageBox_Error(_T("takeOwnership"));
    return 0;
}

// Disable the SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME privilege.
if (!setPrivilege(hToken, SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME, FALSE))
{
    if (pSIDAdmin)
        FreeSid(pSIDAdmin);
    if (hToken)
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    MyMessageBox_Error(_T("takeOwnership"));
    return 0;
}

return 1;
```

}

BOOL ADDirectorySearch::logOnByUserPassword(CString strDomainName, CString strUserName, CString strPassword)
{

```
CString strUPNUserName = strUserName + _T("@") + strDomainName;

HANDLE hToken;
BOOL bResult;
//bResult = LogonUser(strUserName, strDomainName, strPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
//  &hToken);
if (strDomainName != _T(""))
{
    bResult = LogonUser(strUPNUserName, _T(""), strPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, 
        &hToken);
}
else
{
    bResult = LogonUser(strUserName, _T("."), strPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, 
        &hToken);
}
if (bResult == FALSE)
{
    MyMessageBox_Error(_T("logOnByUserPassword Error."), _T("Error"));
    return FALSE;
}
else
{
    bResult = ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken);
    if (bResult == FALSE)
    {
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("logOnByUserPassword Error."), _T("Error"));
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local admins are subject to the usual Windows security checks with one exception: they can always take ownership of a secured object regardless of the permissions.  This ensures that admins are always able to regain control.

However, you are not trying to take ownership, you are trying to read the current owner and you don't necessarily have permission to do that.

It's not clear from your code why you are trying to read the owner.  You don't seem to do anything with it.  Maybe remove the call to GetNamedSecurityInfo altogether.

**Update**

The intention is to write a program that checks the DACLs on every share.  So it needs to save the current owner, take ownership, read the DACLs and restore the owner.  But the current owner cannot be read until ownership has been taken.

I think this behaviour is by design.  The original intention was that admins were able to take ownership, but not hide the fact that they had from the owner of an object, though there are ways around this.  For example, for files you can read the complete security descriptor (including the owner) by enabling the backup privilege, calling BackupRead and parsing the output (a sequence of WIN32_STREAM_ID structures each followed by data).  I don't know if there's a simpler way.

Information about shares is stored in the registry under:

`SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares`

The security info seems to be stored in the `Security` subkey, in a value named after the share.  This binary value seems to be a security descriptor so you can read the owner with [`GetSecurityDescriptorOwner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You can also read all the other security info from this security descriptor, so you shouldn't need to change the owner at all.

Comment: I have a SetNamedSecurityInfo call after the GetNamedSecurityInfo. The SetNamedSecurityInfo function makes the account I pass by arguments the owner. This is in the takeOwnership method. I just wonder how to make Windows believe i'm a Local Admins account and permit me to take the owner? I wrote logOnByUserPassword method for this but don't know if it's right or wrong?

Comment: Yes, but if `GetNamedSecurityInfo` fails (which it might, even if you are an admin) you never call `SetNamedSecurityInfo`.

Comment: oh... I know where's wrong. You mean I can only take the owner instead of reading it. I'd like to explain my full functionality so you'll know why I do this:I wrote this soft to read all shared folders' DACLs. But sometimes a folder even forbid Domain Admin to read it. So I use this "Take Ownership" method to get all folders' DACLs, but I don't want to change the domain or servers after using the software.

Comment: Here's the steps: 1)set owner to Domain Admin 2)set a read permission to Domain Admin 3)read the Security Descriptor of the folder(then read the DACL) 4)restore the original permission 5)restore the original owner. So you see I need to get the owner first by GetNamedSecurityInfo before restoring it. How to resolve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Great job! And I still have a few questions. You seem to address two ways: 1)get SD by calling the BackupRead. 2)get SD from the registry key. for 1) i noticed a handle is needed for the function, so how to get a handle of a remote shared folder? 2)I always believe there're two SDs for a shared folder, a Share one and a NTFS one(I don't know if this understanding's right, but i have written two functions to get both the SDs and it seems to work). I don't know which one is the Security registry key?

Comment: BackupRead gives you the NTFS permissions.  The Remarks section of the MSDN docs on `CreateFile` explain how to open a directory (basically, use `OPEN_EXISTING`, `GENERIC_READ` and `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`).  The security descriptor in the registry gives you the share permissions.

Comment: I tried your BackupRead method as the CreateFile call returned ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED when accessing a shared folder with blank share permissions.PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR ADPermissionSearch::openFile(CString strServerName, CString strFileName)
{
 CString strUNCFileName = _T("\\\\") + strServerName + _T("\\") + strFileName;
 _bstr_t bstrUNCFileName = _bstr_t(strUNCFileName);

 HANDLE hFolder = CreateFile(bstrUNCFileName, GENERIC_READ | ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
  FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
 if (hFolder != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
 {

Comment: The called code is below, I also tried impersonation with the Domain Admin account, I hadn't set privilege yet but I thought it has nothing to do with the CreateFile call?                                             ADDirectorySearch::logOnByUserPassword("domaintest.net", "administrator", "123456Ad");
 ADPermissionSearch::openFile("veotax", "no_one_can_read_me_haha");
 ADDirectorySearch::logOff();

Comment: You do need to set the backup privilege before calling CreateFile.  You can open a shared folder using CreateFile as "\\computer\sharedfolder" or "C:\realpath\sharedfolder" or "\\computer\c$\realpath\sharedfolder".  Even using the backup privilege, the first option may well fail if the share permissions won't let you in (though I haven't tried it).  If you can run your code locally (which will make everything simpler) use the second option.  Otherwise try the third option.

Comment: I have successfully called the ADPermissionSearch::modifyPrivilege(SE_BACKUP_NAME, TRUE) to enable the backup privilege and use the first option for CreateFile but no luck: still error code 5. Because I'm supposed to do a remote network shared-folder permission check stuff , so did the second and third option work without knowing objects' disk locations? Or there's some way for me to get the disk location of a shared-folder?

Comment: If you connect to the remote registry to read the share permissions you can get the real path of the shared folder from the same place.

Comment: I'm so glad that it eventually works by your magic method and thanks for your patient answers. A little difference is after getting handle by CreateFile I called the GetKernelObjectSecurity to get SD instead of using BackupRead, because I couldn't find a way to extract SD from the Win32_STREAM_ID  or somewhere else? Hope this change did not matter its effect.

Comment: Also a little pity is that when I left the NTFS permissions blank or even Domain Admin-forbidden, The CreateFile would still return 5, I don't know if there's a easy way to resolve this except the take ownership one, maybe it's some kind of greedy because the current measures are already complex and strong enough:>