# How can I remove ACL from folder that owned by non-existing user

Tags: c#, .net, windows, acl

I am developing a C# application.

I need to change the ACLs on a folder, to do so I am running my program  as elevated administrator, and everything works fine.

The problem is that if the user that owns the folder got deleted from the system, then when I try to take ownership on the folder I get unauthorized exception.

This is the code that fails:

```
 using (new PrivilegeEnabler(Process.GetCurrentProcess(), Privilege.TakeOwnership))
            {
                var directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
                directorySecurity.SetOwner(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User);
                Directory.SetAccessControl(directoryInfo.FullName, directorySecurity);
            }
```

The exception occurs on the line: **directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();**

PrivilegeEnabler is a class defined in [Process Privileges](http://processprivileges.codeplex.com/) , and it's used to take ownership on the file.

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace and full exception message?

Comment: [An explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384220/getnamedsecurityinfo-returns-error-access-denied5-when-writting-owner-of-a-rem/11385551#11385551).  In short, if you don't have permission to read the permissions, the only thing you can do is take ownership.  So you need to take ownership, then read and update the ACL.  I don't know offhand if you can conveniently do this in C#.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241718/taking-ownership-of-files-with-broken-permissions) explain how to do this.

Comment: @arx - this is exactly what I did, but it fails.. apperantly you can set ownership but you can't get access control. I find this very weird...

Comment: That's by design.  If you don't have permission to read the ACL you can't, but to allow administrators to regain control they can take ownership.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.

You need to set the owner, by creating a new access control (without calling to GetAccessControl) and setting the owner to the current process.
and then you can do whatever you want with the file.

```
using (new PrivilegeEnabler(Process.GetCurrentProcess(), Privilege.TakeOwnership))
            {
                //create empty directory security
                var directorySecurity = new DirectorySecurity();
                //set the directory owner to current user
                directorySecurity.SetOwner(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User);
                //set the access control
                Directory.SetAccessControl(directoryInfo.FullName, directorySecurity);
            }
```